# Supporting multiple version of ESLint in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I am using the [ESLint plugin by Dirk Baeumer](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint) in Visual Studio Code.

My project is large and complex and divided into several primary directories. Each directory has its own package.json file, its own `node_modules` directory and its own version of eslint. This is causing havoc after upgrading to ESLint 6 because my [ESLint plugins won't resolve](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/696).

How do I configure the ESLint plugin to respect the eslint version used in each directory? I think it has something to do with the `eslint.workingDirectories` setting, but I don't understand how to use it properly.

Further information:

My project workspace has two root directories, "folder1" and "folder2". The directory structure looks something like this:

```
folder1
  .eslintrc.json -- rules for the entire "folder1" project to follow

  build
  platform
  core
    Makefile
    core-v1
      .eslintrc.json
      Makefile
      package.json -- eslint v4
      node_modules
    core-v2
      .eslintrc.json
      Makefile
      package.json -- eslint v6
      node_modules
folder2
```

My workspace configuration file includes:

```json
        "eslint.workingDirectories": [
            "./folder1/core/core-v1",
            "./folder1/core/core-v2"
        ]
```

This seems to produce the following error, and no linting errors are detected or highlighted:

```
Uncaught exception received.
Error: spawn /Applications/Visual Studio Code - Insiders.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code - Insiders Helper (Renderer).app/Contents/MacOS/Code - Insiders Helper (Renderer) ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
```

How do I configure the ESLint plugin to use eslint v4 for files in "folder1/core/core-v1" and v6 for files in "folder1/core/core-v2"? My build process runs separate scripts for these directories, but my editor (VS Code) is trying to use a either v4 or v6 to lint all of the files in my project.

Answer (score 3):

First off, the working directories cannot include root folder names:

```
        "eslint.workingDirectories": [
            "./core/core-v1",
            "./core/core-v2"
        ]
```

This seems to correctly identify the working directories and allows version 6 of ESLint to correctly resolve plugins, etc. It also applies v6 rules to core-v2 but still seems to be using the v4 rules for core-v1, so I think this is correct.

One issue that is still not resolve completely is how this works with multi-root workspaces. This works fine for `folder1`. `folder2` just seems to be working, though I can't explain why since it's not identified as a working directory. Thankfully there are no conflicting paths, but what would I do if there were? That may be worth a separate question, but I seem to be up and running now.